# $H$ and $K$ are normal subgroups of a group $G$ with $K \le H$, then $aK =H \iff a \in H$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

> Let $H$ and $K$ are normal subgroups of a group $G$ with $K \le H$.
> How can I prove that $aK =H \iff a \in H$?

I‘m stuck with the part when $a \in H$ then $aK$ contains $H$.

Given $u$ in $H$, how can I show that $u \in aK$ ？

Thanks for helping.

Comment: The statement seems wrong. if $G$ is finite and $K$ is a proper subset of $H$ then the coset $aK$ should have the same cardinality as $K$ hence cannot be the entire subgroup $H$? Is $aK$ denoting something other than the coset, or maybe the claim is only containment?

Comment: It is in the proof of Third isomorphism theorem. The author define $f ： G/K \to G/H$ by $f（aK）=aH$ and want to see that $ker f =H/K$

Comment: this is not the same claim. That follows since $a \in H$ if and only if $aK \in H/K$ when viewed as a subset of $G/K$.

Comment: You should accept one of the answers. Otherwise the question is listed as unanswered and you get more counterexamples.

Comment: thanks for answering my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work as a a counterexample:
Let $G = \mathbb Z$, $H = 2\mathbb Z$ and $K = 4\mathbb Z$. Since $G$ is abelian, $K, H \trianglelefteq G$, and $K\le H$. Now we can choose $a \in H$, say $a = 2$, and consider $aK = 2 + 4\mathbb Z$. This doesn't contain $H$, as for example $4 \in H$ but $4 \notin aK$.

Answer (score 0):

The statement is definitely incorrect. Take $K$ to be the trivial subgroup and $H=G$, for example. Then $a=G$ if and only if $a\in G$ is a nonsense. If we take $aK$ to mean $\langle a,K\rangle$ then it is still absurd, as it would imply that all groups are cyclic.

Nope, something's wrong here.